# jQuery.validate.js Error labels beneath textfields

Tags: jquery, validation

Im using jquery.validate.js for form validation but i cant seem to fix the fact that the error labels show to the right of the input fields. I want them to appear beanth the input fields.

does anyone know how to get this result?

// edit

Solved it:

i went inside jquery.validate.js

edited the following:

```
// from line 627
627. showLabel: function(element, message) {
628. message = "<br>"+message;
```

Comment: I think editing the script isn't the best solution, I think you could achieve it via css with clear

Comment: Changing script is not a great approach. The change you have made will make it non validating XHTML as the <br> is not a closed. It would be better to wrap the message in a div which is a block element as so would normally flow onto the next line. CSS can also then be used for any additional adjustments. In fact, use CSS to place the error message span where you want it (set the display of the span to 'block').

Answer (score 1):

while it worked to edit the validate script directly that may not be very maintainable down the road or may not be an option for someone viewing this question later.

Here's an alternative,

jQuery validation errors generate something like:

```
<label for="input1" generated="true" class="error">This field is required</label>
```

it also adds class "error" to the input element itself `<input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" class="required`**error**`" />`

So to style the error and in this case make it show under the input you can do something like...

CSS:

```
label.error {
    display:block;
}
```